# Should I use Func<T> in place of a private method?

Tags: c#, func, class-members

I'm posting it here and not code review because I want to know if the executing program can behave differently because of this (possibly something subtle).

Is a private method:

```
    private int Foo()
    {
        return Bar().Bat();
    }
```

Any different from a private Func?

```
    private Func<int> Foo = () => Bar().Bat();
```

The only reason I'm doing it is to make the code more compact.

Comment: I don't see any benefit in this added complexity. In fact you're slowing down your code to save three lines, when all you'd have to do is write the method body on a single line. `private int Foo() { return Bar().Foo(); }`

Comment: i just wanted to know if it behaved differently, i hadn't made up my mind about the benefit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much difference, but

- you define templated type `int` (possibly type safe, even if it's not visible in current code provided)
- you can use that function like a parameter to pass to another function, that you can do in the firts case too, naturally, but in first case you would need to declare a `delegate` type.
- third is more compact, but the first is more *readable*, imo, so if you do not need some "functional" stuff, I would go for the first choice.

Comment: @AaronAnodide: :) I just edited my post. It depends, I like it for compactness, but imo, it's slightly less readable then the first one.

Comment: You can also you the named function as a parameter... Depends on the parameter type. No need to declare a delegate.

Comment: Second is good to using in "functional" like programming (as much as it possible in `C#`).

Comment: Methods can be implicitly converted to Func with the appropriate parameters. Having a method that gets as a parameter Func<int> will be more than enough for it to accept this.Foo

Answer (score 0):

`Func`s are `delegate`s and encapsulates any methods that has equal signatur og `Func`. for layering I recomment that you use `Private Methods`

Answer (score 0):

With the Func, you are actually saving a reference to an anonymous method. The compiler creates a named method out of it, and what you're doing is like saving an extra reference to it.

That being not too big of a deal, there isn't much of a difference, except the standard is naming the method. It is also more logical and readable.